# pfsense usb ethernets disabling eachother

Tags: pfsense

Using pfsense 2.6.0, i've two identical usb ethernet with realtek chipset (i know it's a bad choice but every seller in my country have the same chinese crap so i'm stuck with it).

I've installed Realtek kmod pkg, ethernets working single without any problem, but if i plug-in both of them then the problem begins.

1st ethernet is lan as 10.0.0.1/24, 2nd ethernet is captive portal as 10.100.0.1/24, if i don't restart the system all going well.

When i restart the pfsense then LAN ethernet and it's dhcp stops, ethernet speed is becomes empty on dashboard (screenshot as attached) and all lan devices getting ip from Captive portal's dhcp range, so basicly when i restart pfsense captive portal's ethernet kills LAN.

I thought maybe usb ethernet is faulty and changed with identical one and with another brand (brand is different but as i mentioned most probably the same chipset) but all the time captive portal's ethernet kills LAN and serving ip from captive portal's dhcp range to the LAN devices.

The mind blowing thing is My captive portal doesn't even connected to LAN switch, it's directly connected to access point, somehow LAN ethernet dies and captive portal becomes LAN.

I've no idea how does this happens so any help appreciated.
[image]